# Json does not accept {}?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm beginner.

I tried this online editor https://www.jsoneditoronline.org replacing

```
Hello World
```

with

```
Hello {World}
```

but she does not like.

How to include such characters as { and } in json string ?

Update : I don't want to have hello as key I do want BRACES as part of my strING so all the Comments and response are not what I want. I do want something like this except it does not work

```
    {"myKey": "Hello {World}"}
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. Did you remember to add quotes around it?

Comment: make sure it's in a string `{"Hello": "{World}"}`

Comment: @Juhana that's not what I want see my update

Comment: @Moogs that's not what I want see my update

Comment: @user310291 you mention ` {"myKey": "Hello {World}"}` does not work but it does http://jsonfiddle.net/lvyom . I'm not understanding your question

Comment: @Moogs I tried in the link I gave it didn't work. Fine if it works with your link thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What's the error message you get? When I copy-paste that exact thing into jsoneditoronline and click the button it creates the object without problems.

Comment: @Juhana I tried on my iPad maybe it is not fully compatible. Will try again on desktop thanKS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by **Hello {World}**, but the json structure is:

`{type1:value1, type2:value2}`.

So if you want to have a json with the string "Hello world", your json would be:

```
 {string:"Hello world"}.
```

Comment: That is invalid JSON structure. Keys must be Strings (wrapped in quotes). `{"myKey": "Hello World"}`

Comment: @mihaivladu thanks but I want "Hello {World}" not "Hello World"